# 参加 vs 参与 - cānjiā vs cānyu

Tags: vocabulary

So, these two both mean 'to participate in' and there doesn't seem to be any difference in the types of things one might participate in.
Are they therefore interchangeable?
Thanks!
Hashamyim

P.s. I am categorising my 'what are the difference' questions under 'vocabulary'. As they are all HSK 5 verbs, should I open a new HSK5 tag? What do you reckon?

Comment: Thanks guys. For some reason, that didn't come up in the search results

Answer (score 0):

additional information：＂汉语动词３８０例＂参加／参与 例 释 **一、** **参加** **１.** 这词运动会他参加了五个项目的比赛。动词＂参加＂的意思是加入某种组织或某种活动又例如：a。他要去参加下个星期在上海举行的学术会议。b。他参加了中国教育代表团，下个月去欧洲访问。c。关于这个城市的建设计划他参加过讨论。**２。** 是否组织旅行？你能参加点儿意见吗？＂参加＂在这儿的意思是对某事或某一问题提出意见。又例如：a。这个问题还得请大家多参加参加意见。b。我参加不了多少意见，还是听听大家的。＂参加＂表示这种意思的时候，可以重叠使用，但它通常不单独做谓语。**二、参与１。** 他曾参与过这个计划的讨论。动词＂参与＂的意思是进入到某事物的计划、讨论、处理等活动中去。又例如：a。跟你无关的事你别参与进去。b。我从没参与过他们的活动。＂参与＂跟＂参加＂在这儿意思是相同，可以相互替换，但＂参加＂的意思更广泛，＂参与＂不含加入某种组织的意思。

**＂汉语同义词词典＂** 加入／参与／参加［同］动词。表示投身于其中。［异］**［加入］** 着重于投身于某种组织，成为其中的成员。通用于口语和书面语。例：（１）当我发现了中国革命的正确道路时，我便加入了中国共产党。（朱德＜母亲的回忆＞）（２）我不久就加入了学生军。预备北伐！（田汉＜创作经验谈＞）（３）在县城里出售了茧后，他找着了他的战友，竟加入到战友的包工队里，一住就是两个月没有回来。（贸平凹＜鸡窝洼的人家＞）

**［参与］** 又作＂**参预**＂。着重于投身于某种活动。用于书面语。文言语体。例：（１）在画栋雕梁的怀仁堂里，我参与一次代大会。（柯灵＜历史老人摊了牌＞）（２）左翼作家参预或亲历实际革命斗争，使创作面貌继续有所变化；。。。（严家谈＜＜中国现代各流派小说选＞前言）（３）家里人都看我不起，因为我是女的，又穷又小，大小事都不让我参预。（丁玲＜我怎样跟文学结下了＂缘分＂＞）（４）伯韩就这样在风雨中喘息，在喘息中写作。同时，所有的一切政治活动，他都参与其事。（张毕来＜悼念曹伯韩同志＞）

**［参加］** 着重于投身于某种组织或某种活动。使用范围比＂加入＂、＂参与＂宽。通用于口语和书面语。例：（１）一九四四年，闻一多参加了中国民主同盟，担任了＜民主周刊＞的编委。（赵遐秋＜闻一多和他的＜最后一次的讲演＞）（２）我脱离了地方，带了一批同志，参加了大部队。（谌容＜永远是春天＞）（３）＂你到上海去找觉慧也好，横竖我们可以联络，你也可以问参加我们的工作，＂张惠如说。（巴金＜秋＞）（４）果然，回回两口参加了禾禾的婚礼，在鸡窝洼里落了个好名声。（贾平凹＜鸡窝洼的人家＞）（５）从这以后，赵满囤就参加了田间劳动。（马烽＜三年早知道＞）

**［附］** ＂**加入**＂还表示加上；搀进去，如＂菜里边要加入少许糖＂。＂**参加**＂还表示提出，如＂请参加意见＂＞

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
If something will make a result, 
then "参与" means you have rights to make the decision.
and "参加" only means you just sit in the corner and listen to others.

Comment: 参加 = join. If you join a mission, you are a part of a team, you are expected to act; if you join a meeting, you are expected to give input.